# Serializing Linq2sql model selectively to JSON

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, extension-methods, json.net

I have quite common linq2sql bussiness model from mssql database. There are some associations between tables, which is good. Whole model is in separate assembly. I am using JSON.NET library for serialization.

Now i need to serialize those models to JSON and tell it which properties to use and which now. Using if attributes is impossible, but i don't like idea of metadata class either.

So i had been thinking about using extension method in this manner:

```
public static class User {
  public static object GetSerializable(this DataModel.User user) {
    return new {
      user.Id, user.LoginName, user.FirstName, user.LastName
    }
  }
}
```

This would nice, however i am not sure how to use it in cases like this:

```
[JsonObject]
public class AuthModel {
  [JsonProperty]
  public DataModel.User { get; set; }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to effectively use those extensions methods there ? Or some other completely different ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right i had decided for approach based on custom JsonConverter which is in result very similar to that approach above. It looks like this:

```
public abstract class SerializeSelectorConverter<TModel> : JsonConverter where TModel: class
{
    protected abstract object GetSerializableObject( TModel model );

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(TModel);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, GetSerializableObject( value as TModel ));
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then i just make a class like:

```
[JsonObject]
public class AuthModel {
    [JsonProperty]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UserConverter))]
    public DataModel.User { get; set; }
}

private class UserConverter : SerializeSelectorConverter<DataModel.User>
{
    protected override object GetSerializableObject(DataModel.User model)
    {
        return new
        {
            model.Id,
            model.LoginName,
            model.FirstName,
            model.LastName
        };
    }
}
```

Simple enough without some complex configuration or metadata classes. Everything is properly validated by compiler, so no typos and problems when changes occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fluent Json](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-json/) to convert them to json. This configuration can be done in code without using attributes.

Option 2 : You can use [Custom Serializer](http://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/02/26/a-custom-converter-for-json-net/)

Option 3 : You can use the [KeyValuePairConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_KeyValuePairConverter.htm). Convert your persistant class to a dictionary and use this.

Comment: Thank you ! Fluent Json looks interesting, i will think about using it instead of json.net. Custom converter could be an option, but i am keeping it as last resort. KeyValuePair is however useless or i don't how exactly do you mean to use it.

Comment: Allright...Fluent Json is nice, but it's too much explicit. I like this for JSON.NET, that it's able to serialize simple object without any configuration in default. Custom converter is rather limited for this purpose, there is no reference to property itself, so i cannot read additional attribute with information about serialization.

Comment: Yes Json.NET is smooth and requires no configuration. But in your case you do need configuration, and you are not able to use attributes. If you definitely want to use Json.NET create a POCO with all the Json attributes like JsonIgnore etc applied and map your persistent class to this POCO. So your mapper and POCO will give you fine control over what becomes json.

Comment: Yes i need configuration, but just for a few cases. Most of the time it will be just about filtering out unwanted properties from those fixed classes. I don't need much of fine grain approach. I don't know exactly what you mean by POCO, but i don't want end with creating some "shadow" classes with same named properties which tells me what to really serialize. In case of some change, the compiler will be silent.

Comment: POCO = Plain Old CLR Object. Its good that you went with Custom converter - it was Option 2 - and better than creating shadow classes like you said.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a custom JsonConverter to handle this kind of case generically given that the source class has an interface enumerating what needs to be serialized.

Your class plus serialization interface:

```
public interface IUser {
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    string LoginName { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class User : IUser {
    ...implementation...
}
```

The converter:

```
public class InterfaceExtractorJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter {
    private class InterfaceDictionary<T> : Dictionary<string, object> { }

    private PropertyInfo[] InterfaceProperties {
        get { return typeof(T).GetProperties(); }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var dictionary = new InterfaceDictionary<T>();
        foreach (var property in InterfaceProperties) {
            dictionary[property.Name] = value.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(value, null);
        }
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dictionary);
    }

    private object ReadNestedObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) {
            if (!reader.Read())
                throw new Exception("Unexpected end.");
        }

        switch (reader.TokenType) {
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
            case JsonToken.Integer:
            case JsonToken.Float:
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Boolean:
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.Undefined:
            case JsonToken.Date:
            case JsonToken.Bytes:
                return reader.Value;
            default:
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Unexpected token when converting object: {0}", reader.TokenType));
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        while (reader.Read()) {
            switch (reader.TokenType) {
                case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                    string propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();

                    if (!reader.Read())
                        throw new Exception("Unexpected end.");


                    if (!InterfaceProperties.Any(p => p.Name.Equals(propertyName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) {
                        reader.Skip();
                        continue;
                    }
                    var property = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                    var innerObj = ReadNestedObject(reader, property.PropertyType, existingValue, serializer);

                    property.SetValue(obj, innerObj, null);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                    return obj;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Unexpected end.");
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return objectType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

A lot of optimizations can be made to the converter...